# Playing a youtube video in full screen mode in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am connecting to a website which hosts youtube videos via webview. When I click on the youtube video it works fine - the player plays within the webvideo window. But when I make the video full screen it plays. But when I press the back button - it goes back to the webview and I can navigate to the rest of my app - but I can still hear the video play in the background. Whats happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found a solution here on StackOverflow. I don't have link to that question though.

Here it is:

```
webview.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8");
```